# Why didn't copying my home folder to a new machine preserve all preferences?

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, migration

So, I needed to move my existing data to a new machine. I expected basically all settings (e.g. google chrome bookmarks, nav bar contents in gnome3, etc.) to be preserved if I simply copied my `$HOME` to the new machine. This is what I did:

1. Installed all packages from old installation: `sudo yum install -y $(cat old-rpm-list.txt)`.
2. Mounted old drive in new fedora 19 installation:
   `vgscan && vgchange -a y` and `mount /dev/f19old/home /mnt/oldhome`)
3. Copied old home directory to new home directory: `cp -avpr --preserve=all /mnt/oldhome/user /home/`.
4. Update all packages and restarted: `sudo yum update -y && reboot`

So, since all the preference files (`~/.*`) were moved to the new installation, I thought everything would be preserved. But my chrome doesn't have my bookmarks and my nav bar and VPN settings (gnome preferences, I presume) were not preserved.

Have I missed some files I needed to come over from `/etc/` or something?

Comment: Do your old and new user have the same UID?

Comment: @matthiaskrull Yes. Old: `uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user),10(wheel),1001(vboxusers) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023`. 

New:
`uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user),10(wheel) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023`

Comment: Why do you think you don't have the same preferences?  Are you sure your problem isn't related to changes in the software you are running?

Comment: @Zoredache There shouldn't be any changes to the software running. Both the old and new should have the same packages installed and were fully up to date. Additionally, my virt-manager doesn't have any of the VMs it used to.

Answer (score 1):

> So, since all the preference files (~/.*) were moved to the new installation

Sounds like they weren't to me.

The cp command you used may not have copied any hidden folders / files that are in your home directory. Given that's where a vast majority (if not all) user specific preferences are held, it looks likely that they have not been copied over.

run this in your OLD home folder

```
ls -la
```

To show a folder listing with hidden folders. They all start with .
You can either try copying them one by one, or you can do something like this:

```
cp -var {.config,.VirtualBox,.mozilla} /your/new/home/folder/location
```

That said, Ive always been a fan of rsync myself

```
rsync -var --progress /home/CHK /newhome
```

Once its finished copying, make sure the ownership of the folder is correct by issuing

```
chown -R CHK:CHK /home/CHK
```

ps. Also -p and --preverse-all are the same

Comment: Timestamps indicate hidden file copy worked:`
user@work ~ $ ls -la | head
total 12660
drwx--x---+ 78 user user     4096 Dec 10 14:02 .
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root    root        4096 Jul  8 04:56 ..
drwxrwxr-x.  2 user user     4096 Nov 25 15:13 .389-console
drwx------.  3 user user     4096 Apr 17  2013 .adobe
drwxrwxr-x.  9 user user     4096 May 28  2013 apache-tomcat-6.0.26
drwxrwxr-x.  4 user user     4096 Jun 14 16:35 apps
drwxrwxr-x.  9 user user     4096 Nov  1 17:18 backup
-rw-------.  1 user user    36047 Dec 10 14:09 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--.  1 user user       18 Nov 29  2012 .bash_logout`

Comment: Also, the man page says `-p` == `--preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps` and I believe there are 6 total possible (those 3 and context, links, xattr). `=all` tries to do them all.